# Java volatile and happens-before

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile, happens-before

There is what java spec says about it:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5
"A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field."
But what does "subsequent" mean in terms of concurrency? How can we be sure what is subsequent ans what is previous? Let's write a simple test:

```
public class VolatileTest {

    static /*volatile*/ int counter = 0;
    static int zeros = 0;
    static int ones = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        int i = 0;
        while (i++ < 1_000_000) {
            if (i % 100_000 == 0) System.out.println(i);
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(VolatileTest::op1);
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(VolatileTest::op2);
            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();

            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();

            counter = 0;
        }

        System.out.println("Zeros " + zeros);
        System.out.println("Ones " + ones);
    }


    public static void op1() {
        counter = 1;
    }

    public static void op2() {
        if (counter == 0) ++zeros;
        if (counter == 1) ++ones;
    }
}
```

The final output will be like

```
Zeros 2095
Ones 997905
```

And it is predictable.
But when i uncomment the `volatile` word in `counter` variable, i still get some zeros in the answer, which means that read from volatile `count` variable was before the write, despite java spec claims that

> write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field.

Where am i wrong?

Comment: Re, "...still get some zeros." The version with `volatile` gets fewer zeros because the assignment `counter=1` propagates to thread2 more quickly than without `volatile`, but there's nothing in your code that _guarantees_ that thread1 actually will set `counter=1` before thread2 tests it.  Sometimes, thread2 will get to test `counter` before thread1 sets it. Also note, it's possible for thread2 to sometimes increment both `zeros` and `ones` because it tests `counter` twice, and it's possible for `counter` to change in between the two tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A write operation to `volatile` variable is immediately visible to all the threads. More importantly, any write operation that happens before the volatile write will also become visible. So in the following code:

```
static volatile int counter = 0;
static int x = 0;

...
// A single thread writes to the counter
x = 1;
counter = 1;
```

For all other threads that run:

```
if(counter==1) {
  // Here, x = 1 is guaranteed
}
```

The value of `x` is not guaranteed to be 1 if `counter` is not volatile. The compiler or the CPU may reorder the memory write operations without the `volatile`.

Comment: @Hulk, good point. Edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

"Subsequent" here means some order in which JVM/OS would order volatile variable accesses. You couldn't directly control that order.
Marking a field as volatile also doesn't specify that order.

Starting `thread1` before `thread2` as you do increases probability that `thread1` instructions would be ordered before `thread2` instructions, but doesn't guarantee that. Both threads runs in parallel with just a tiny difference at start time, so it's a matter of chance, which one op would be actually executed first by computer. Thread1 just have a little more chances.

Comment: This is a good answer, it's fair to point out that the OS or JVM will order threads as it likes, and order of execution is not guaranteed.  People often miss the idea that threads are asynchronous.  That said, I'd describe "subsequent" as "wall clock time."  If the physical time measured by some arbitrary clock makes one event subsequent to another, that's what the spec means.  It means the read actually happened after the write.  *Happens-before* is different than wall clock time, it's a term of art that means the value is visible.